# Get all values for a matched highlight field from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index that contains a string field with email addresses. I search for them with a boolean field query containing also a highlighting rule on that field.

The documents can contain more than one address. The addresses are imported as an Array. On the search results page I want all emails of the matched document to have displayed and have only the matched one to be highlighted.

Can I tell elasticsearch to also return the unmatched values of the matching document inside `highlight`? Or do I have to merge it manually with `_source`?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Ashalynd I will have a look into facets. (we are running 0.90).

Comment: So I did not find any improvement in facets. So I continue merging the data on my own.

Comment: Are you still merging the data on your own? I have the same issue.

Comment: Just for future reference: Yes we kept doing that. @DonnyV.